# Converting rectangular pixels to square pixels in R

Tags: r, gis, pixel, resolution

I'm working with an asc file in R and trying to run it through some GIS processing on a script that was written by someone else. The current chunk of code I'm working on is

`asc <- (raster(inputRas))`

`asc.extent  <- extent(asc)`

`head <- read.ascii.grid.header(inputRas)`

`writeRaster(asc, "outputRas", format="SAGA", overwrite=TRUE)`

which works until the last line. It's failing here because my raster is in rectangular coordinates, which SAGA doesn't like. I've spent a lot of time googling and trying different functions, but nothing has worked that didn't cause other problems down the line. I considered using projectRaster() for a while because the resolution can be changed within it, but I don't actually want to change the projection. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `raster::projectRaster`, you can use `raster::resample`

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to redefine the resolution within the resample() function. It seems as though I need another raster layer with the parameters (e.g. square pixels of the right size) to act as a "template" but I don't have another raster with those specifications. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can create one using  the input data and the `res` method